# Heterogeneity of time invariant characteristic in event study model

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics, applied-econometrics, difference-in-difference

I am trying to estimate the impact that the onset of a medical disease has on a number of outcomes, call them $O$. To do this, I am using an event study model with individual and time fixed effects...
\begin{equation}
    O_{i,t} = \alpha + \sum_{\substack{k=S \\ k\neq -1}}^{F}{\mu_k} + Z_{i,t}\delta + \sigma_i + \epsilon_{i,t}
\end{equation}

I have theoretical reason to believe that characteristics of the individual at the onset of the individual may moderate the effect of disease onset, and so I would like to explore heterogeneity in the treatment effect by this at-diagnosis characteristic. For instance, an individual's marital status at diagnosis may moderate his response following diagnosis.

I apologize if this is a trivial question but how can I incorporate this time invariant characteristic into a model with the individual effect? Should I simply run subsample analysis by group? And if so, what is a good strategy for dealing with continuous (but fixed) heterogeneity -- for instance, heterogeneity of income at diagnosis? Should I drop the individual fixed effect?

I appreciate all of your assistance and thoughts in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a time-constant covariate $X$, you could include it but drop the individual fixed effects $\sigma_i$. (There could be perfect multicollinearity if you kept them.) Since you mentioned that $X$ might have a moderating effect w.r.t. $Z$, you would include interaction terms between $X$ and $Z$. So you would have something like
$$
O_{i,t} = \alpha + \beta_t + \gamma x_i + \delta Z_{i,t} + \theta (x_i\cdot Z_{i,t}) + \epsilon_{i,t}
$$
with $\beta_t$ being time fixed effects. You could set $\beta_1=0$ for identification. (One more linear restriction might be needed.) From your verbal description of the problem, I am not sure what $\sum_{\substack{k=S \\ k\neq -1}}^{F}{\mu_k}$ is meant to represent, so I did not include it in the equation above.

<sub>(I might be completely wrong. It has been a long while since I did anything with panel data models.)</sub>

Comment: Without the individual fixed effect, it would not be a DiD anymore? I think a better approach would be to keep the individual fixed effects and run two separate estimations for the sub-samples.

Comment: @Papayapap, hm, I don't know. Is that possible if $X$ and the individual effects are perfectly multicollinear? Now regarding your suggestions, how would you define the subsamples and what estimations do you have in mind?

Comment: Marital status is binary, so we can use two sample for marital status=1 and marital status=0

Comment: @Papayapap, for a binary variable like that it sounds like a good idea.